# How to design Comment table that can reference either Question table or Answer table?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, database-design, entity-framework-core

For illustration purposes, let's consider 3 tables: `Question`, `Answer` and `Comment` with the following ORM models (in C#).

- A question can have zero or more answers and/or comments.
- An answer belongs to a question and can have zero or more comments.
- A comment belongs to either a question or an answer.

The rules mimic SO/SE mechanism.

```cs
class Question 
{
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public string Content {get; set;}
  public IEnumerable<Answer> Answers {get; set;}
  public IEnumerable<Comment> Comments {get; set;}
}
```

```cs
class Answer
{
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public string Content {get; set;}
  public Question Question {get; set;}
  public IEnumerable<Comment> Comments {get; set;}
}
```

```cs
class Comment
{
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public string Content {get; set;}
  public ?????? For {get; set;}
}
```

## Question

I have no idea how to construct the `Comment` table in which the property `For` can be either `Question` or `Answer`. What is the type of `For` property?

Comment: You are describing a many-to-many relationship.  Please consult [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#many-to-many) about this topic.

Comment: @KirkWoll: I have read the docs before. I have no idea why the essence of this question is about many-to-many relationship.

Comment: Because this is a canonical example of a use-case for many-to-many?  Either that, or two separate one-to-many relationships, as Parsa described, in which case you have two separate foreign keys (and/or corresponding navigation properties) in `Comment`, one for each parent type.

Comment: @KirkWoll : I just knew a table can have more than one foreign key and they can be null. Thank you. 
I thought a table can only have one foreign key and it cannot be null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nothing! leave it to `EF`, it will manage these relations. as a note, I can say the relations are one-to-many each `Answer` and `Question` has own `Comment` so if you want to put foreign keys you must use two keys for both of them

Comment: I just knew a table can have more than one foreign key and they can be null. Thank you. 
I thought a table can only have one foreign key and it cannot be null.